# array of data in a drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the area table of my database to display in a drop down menu but I am having trouble because it is an array.

In my controller I have: `$data['city'] = $this->location->fetchCity();`

but in my view when I go `<?php echo $city; ?>` I get this `Array` why?

**Model:**

```
public function fetchCity(){
    $this->db->select('area');
    $this->db->from('suburbs');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->result();
    }
```

**Update:**

```
    <select>
        <?php foreach ($city as $key => $row): ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['area'];?>"><?php echo $row['area'];?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. you say `$data['city']` holds an array from `fetchCity()` function yet you echo $city. Can you please show us how you're echoing out the results and a `print_r()` of the returned array from `fetchCity()` as this is most likely where the issue arises.

Comment: What you can do to get a better idea of what your code is returning is to use this after you return data:

    `echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    exit;`

Comment: can you please show the result of `print_r()` statement?

Comment: @Shahzeb sure http://d.pr/i/GxHf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $city[$key]; ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo $city['area']; ?>
```

Since your function call returns an Array, this is how I suggest you print it out.

---

```
foreach ($city as $key=>$row)
{ 
   echo $row->area; 
}
```

Since your result is an Array of Objects, I'm sure this will get things right.

Comment: Thanks,  I now get Message:  Undefined index: area

Comment: did you try the first one? put it inside a `foreach` loop and try it out. I think that should solve the problem

Comment: @JessMcKenzie if you are using Shazeb's answer, I presume you've missed out the html **option** tags.

Comment: `echo $row->area;`
This will solve your problem. 
Since your result is in form of an array of objects.